# Angular Js UI grid ,Export to pdf I want to add logo image in pdf header

Tags: angularjs, export-to-pdf

I am new in angular js  and I want to add image in exported pdf file of angular js grid.

I have tried below code but there is no success still.

- exporterPdfHeader: { text: "Header ", style: 'headerStyle' },
             },
             exporterPdfCustomFormatter: function (docDefinition) {
                 docDefinition.styles.headerStyle = { fontSize: 18, bold: true, margin: [20, 15, 0, 0],width:475
                    ,image : url('http://localhost:57910/Images/Logo_2.png')
                    ,background: url('http://localhost:57910/Images/Logo_2.png')
                     ,background:'blue'